# Data retrieval delay from resultset java

Tags: java, performance, oracle11g, query-optimization, resultset

I have to get some data by joining two tables so I have make a view that contains the join and order by options. As well as I have used indexes for columns in where clause but when retrieving a data set about 150 records it delays. Normally it retrieves 12 records per second. (DB used: Oracle 11g)
Could you please help me to find a optimization technique for this?

Tables:

```
Employee{eid,fnmae,lname,did,sal_cat,reg_id}

Departments{did,dname,dhead}
```

View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EmpDep AS
SELECT e.eid,e.fname,e.lname,d.dname,e.reg_id
FROM employee e, deparments d
WHERE sal_cat='A' and e.did=d.did
ORDER BY e.did,d.did;
```

Query in JAVA:

```
SELECT eid,fname,dname FROM EmpDEP
WHERE reg_id="US";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EmpDep AS
SELECT e.eid,e.fname,e.lname,d.dname,e.reg_id
FROM employee e INNER JOIN deparments d ON e.did=d.did
WHERE sal_cat='A' ORDER BY e.did,d.did;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice ! Actually I tired with this too but still it is with that issue.